# column depend on the other columns in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I have 2 tables which has structure like this

```
mysql> select * from customer;
+-------+-------+
| cname | ccode |
+-------+-------+
| Sumit | c1    |
| Amit  | c2    |
| Sunil | c3    |
+-------+-------+

mysql> select * from supplier;
+-------+-------+
| sname | scode |
+-------+-------+
| Suraj | s1    |
| Naresh| s2    |
| Parul | s3    |
+-------+-------+
```

In 3rd form values of both tables I have pass to option tag so that user can select one of them.
When data will be stored in mysql I would to have answer like bellow

```
+-------------+--------+------+
|account_name | amount | code |
+-------------+--------+------+
| Amit        | 100    | c2   |
| Parul       | 400    | s3   |
| Suraj       | 100    | s1   |
+-------------+--------+------+
```

That code column needs to filled automatically because I have not display any code value in my jsp form.

Can any please suggest me something?

Comment: there should be some relatiohship between table colums to show up

Comment: can you please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly :) ...

When customers and supplier codes are unique, you can use union clause with same word for searching in both tables:

```
    insert into thirdtable (account_name,amount,code) values ('wujek',100,(select ccode code from customer where cname='Sumit' union  select scode code from supplier where sname='Sumit'));

    insert into thirdtable (account_name,amount,code) values ('wujek',100,(select ccode code from customer where cname='Parul' union  select scode code from supplier where sname='Parul'));
```

Comment: This works perfect for me. Thank you @Mikrobi But is this works smoothly for ample of records?

Comment: If your tables with codes are unique and columns in "where" are indexed, Yes.